# Converting grayscale VRT to palleted VRT using GDAL tools

Tags: gdal, convert, vrt

I have this virtual file called **`virtual-raster.vrt`** with the following [`gdalinfo`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html#example) of:

```
Band 1 Block=1x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

I just want to convert it into a palleted one like so:

```
Band 1 Block=1x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
```

With the following color palette (value:color):

```
0 : #000000
1 : #FF0000
2 : #00FF00
3 : #0000FF
```

How to convert a grayscale VRT to a palleted VRT using [GDAL tools](https://gdal.org/programs/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation of VRT https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html and add color table. Step by step example:

Create test image with gdal_create https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_create.html#gdal-create. Utility is included in GDAL version 3.2 and higher.

```
gdal_create -of GTiff -outsize 10 10 -bands 1 -burn 2 -ot Float32  float_gray.tif
```

Create a VRT from the test image with gdal_translate

```
gdal_translate -f vrt float_gray.tif float_gray.vrt
```

The result is close to your VRT, even I wonder the blocksize that you have, 1x1. Do you have only one pixel?

```
gdalinfo float_gray.vrt
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: float_gray.vrt
       float_gray.tif
Size is 10, 10
Corner Coordinates:
...
Band 1 Block=10x10 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Open the VRT file with text editor and add color table as in the documentation

> ColorTable: This element is parent to a set of Entry elements defining
> the entries in a color table. Currently only RGBA color tables are
> supported with c1 being red, c2 being green, c3 being blue and c4
> being alpha. The entries are ordered and will be assumed to start from
> color table entry 0.

```
<ColorTable>   
<Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255"/>
<Entry c1="145" c2="78" c3="224" c4="255"/>
</ColorTable>
```

The whole VRT with reference to TIFF file and color table with three entries would look like

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="10" rasterYSize="10">
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">float_gray.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="10" RasterYSize="10" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="10" BlockYSize="10" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="10" ySize="10" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="10" ySize="10" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <ColorTable>
      <Entry c1="0" c2="0" c3="0" c4="255"/>
      <Entry c1="145" c2="78" c3="224" c4="255"/>
      <Entry c1="255" c2="78" c3="224" c4="255"/>
    </ColorTable>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

Gdalinfo about the modified VRT

```
gdalinfo float_gray.vrt
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: float_gray.vrt
       float_gray.tif
Size is 10, 10
Corner Coordinates:
...
Band 1 Block=10x10 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 3 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 145,78,224,255
    2: 255,78,224,255
```

I leave it to you to convert the colors in hexa format into RGB values.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no readily available GDAL tool for doing this? This answer of somewhat XML-parsing could be the only possible solution though.

Comment: If all that you have is `0 : #000000
1 : #FF0000
2 : #00FF00
3 : #0000FF` I doubt that you can find any full automatic way. Copying palette from an existing image might be possible but I do not know, just wondering.